# Error bar alignment with marker using ErrorListPlot in Mathematica?

Tags: graph, graphics, wolfram-mathematica, errorbar

I'm plotting a scatter plot with error bars. The code is all running fine, but one thing that really bugs me is that the error bars themselves are slightly misaligned from their markers. Here's the relevant portion of my code; there are a couple other things displayed on my graph, but they're not relevant to the error bars.

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"];
logplotDataBars = Transpose[{logxLabels, normYValues, normStdevs}];
```

The variable `logplotDataBars` essentially takes data from whatever .csv file you import, and creates a list of ordered triplets, where the first two variables are the x and y values and the third variable is the length of the error bars. Since it's a function, it can take in values from whatever data file you're using, but here's some example data you could play with:

```
{{9.21034,0.257068,0.0265554},{9.90349,0.491379,0.0906615},{10.5966,0.480906,0.0454253},{11.5129,0.643401,0.144125},{13.8155,0.915444,0.104304},{16.1181,1.,0.217274}}
```

Now I just display my scatterplot overlaid on top of some other curves.

```
scatterPlotErrors = 
  ErrorListPlot[{logplotDataBars, {x, 0, 16}}, PlotStyle -> {Red}, 
   PlotMarkers -> {Automatic}, PlotRange -> {-0.02, 1.3}];
finalPlot = Show[{scatterPlotErrors,
    CurveFit,
    DashedLine}]
```

Now, the plot theoretically works perfectly:

[image: output image]

However, it bugs me that the error bars just always display slightly offset. What's even weirder is that when I save it as a PDF, they appear offset when I view it on my computer, but appear centered when I read it on my phone! How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Seems to be a known issue: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2173/errorlistplot-marker-missaligned-with-error-bar

Comment: Hmm, thanks. Setting opacity to 0.999 seemed to fix it. I'd seen this setting on previous examples of people making error bars, but thought it was just an optional preference. Now I understand why this makes sense.